# \sbox from inside an environment

Tags: latex

I'm trying to save some text inside an environment for later use. The smallest test case I could come up with is this. The saved text in the `sbox` isn't available after the environment is closed. How can I work around that? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\somebox}
\begin{itemize}
\item hello1
\item hello1 \sbox{\somebox}{Some text}
\end{itemize}
This should show something, but does not: "\usebox{\somebox}"
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're running into here is a scoping issue.  In (La)TeX, you can introduce scopes with `{ ... }`, `\bgroup ... \egroup`, or `\begingroup ... \endgroup`.  The former two are roughly the same, as `\bgroup` and `\egroup` are defined by `\let\bgroup{` and `\let\egroup}`; the last one is slightly different.  But the scoping property is the same: any commands, boxen, etc., created or modified within those scopes are not visible outside.  And in LaTeX, all environments `\begin{env} ... \end{env}` implicitly wrap their contents in `\begingroup ... \endgroup`.  This means that your`\sbox{\somebox}{Some text}` modification is only visible until the `\end{itemize}`; after that, the modification is undone.  To get around this, prepend any command like `\newcommand`, `\def`, `\newsavebox`, `\sbox`, etc., with `\global`, which forces the definition to take place at the global scope and be visible everywhere.

Also, to use quotes in (La)TeX, write ``` ``double quoted'' ```, ``` ``double quoted" ```, or `` `single quoted' ``; the `"` character is only for closing quotes, not opening quotes.  Putting this all together gives you the revised snippet

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\somebox}
\begin{itemize}
  \item hello1
  \item hello1 \global\sbox{\somebox}{Some text}
\end{itemize}
This should show something, and in fact does: ``\usebox{\somebox}''
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. That `\global` was indeed the trick

Answer (score 1):

I think I can work around this by using `\def`. like so:

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item hello1
\item hello1
\global \def \somebox {Some text}
\end{itemize}
This should show something: \somebox
\end{document}